# How to get the host protocol in .Net Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have been searching for several hours now and cannot find the answer anywhere. All the results I get are outdated stackoverflow posts with deprecated methods.

The closest I found is `Request.Scheme` but that returns the protocol of the request and not the protocol of the host.

Edit, adding some context:

I want to call `Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { Foo = foo }, protocol: myHostProtocol);` with `myHostProtocol` being set to the current server protocol. `Request.Scheme` returns the protocol of the caller and not my application.

Comment: What do you mean by "protocol of the host"?

Comment: @DavidG http vs https, it used to be accessible via `Request.Url.Scheme` AFAIK.

Comment: @AlexC Are you looking for `HttpContext.Request.IsHttps`?

Comment: @Win, I added some context.

Comment: The protocol of the request *is* the protocol of the host. HTTP/HTTPS is not an intrinsic trait of a web server; it's determined by what the client requests (i.e. a request via HTTPS prompts the server to respond via HTTPS).

Comment: Put another way, if your site has both HTTP and HTTPS bindings, it will fluidly switch between the two based on the request. If the client requests via HTTP, then HTTP will be used. If the client requests via HTTPS, then HTTPS will be used. Even if you remove the HTTP binding, that doesn't make the server inherently HTTPS, it just means it will bounce any requests via HTTP because it simply is not set up to respond to those.